# JSPrintManager unable to print without client app

Tags: reactjs, neodynamic

I am trying to silently print a PDF file using JSPrintManager in a ReactJS project.
It is working fine if JSPrintManager client app intalled on local machine. Is there any way to achieve silent printing without the client app?

Tried adding following scripts in a component

```html
const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "JSPrintManager.js";
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.5/bluebird.min.js";
    script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install the client app to function as expected Since there are dependencies of the JSPrintManager on the Client app.

JSPrintManager (JSPM) App is the client-side part of JSPrintManager Solution. It can be installed on any number of client machines without paying any fees.

Ref: https://www.neodynamic.com/downloads/jspm/